# Free summand of a module vs. finite direct sum of copies of it

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a commutative Noetherian ring $R$. If $R$ is a direct summand of $M^{\oplus n}$ for some $n\ge 1$ , then  is $R$ a direct summand of $M$?

I can easily prove this if $R$ is local, but have a feeling that it is not true if $R$ is not local, although I cannot find a counterexample.

Please help.